# MPI error: ‘OMPI_Comm_agree’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi, openmpi

I am new to MPI programming I have taken up code from a git repository and was trying to run and see how it works. The code was taken from git@github.com:mdmohsinali/ULFM-Process-Failure-Recovery.git. What do you think can be the error.

Do I need to configure anything? or add library?

Comment: What (Open)MPI version do you have? Where and when does the error occur? What compiler?

Comment: I have OpenMPI 1.8.4 complier. the error message is ‘OMPI_Comm_agree’ was not declared in this scope. I get the same message on revoke, OMPI_Comm_failure_ack. Do I need put in ULFM version of complier may be release 1.1 or 1.0?